# Push strangely formatted dates into MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, date-manipulation

I am sure this must be a common question but I cannot find it anywhere so here it goes:

I have dates in this format: `09/Jul/2003:00:03:48 -0300` and I want to push them into a `DATETIME` field in MySQL.

What is the easiest way to do this?  Pushing them in as is results in them being zeroed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL doesn't include the timezone in DATETIMEs, but you can use:

```
STR_TO_DATE('09/Jul/2003:00:03:48', '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%i:%s')
```

...to convert a string representation of a date/time into a DATETIME for storing in the database.

Reference:

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I knew there must be some easy way to do that.  I was looking through php functions and just starting to pull out regex.  This is *way* easier.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: If you're looking for the PHP "equivalent" (it doesn't convert, but it parses it), try [strptime](http://php.net/strptime).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know can not be changed and has to be in the format below:

'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

My favorite function in all of PHP is `strtotime()`. If that can't interpret the input then I probably can't code something that could.

So I would do something like:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($stragely_formatted_date)));
```

to prepare a DATE string to give to MySQL.

As always, think about timezones in your the design.

The `mysql_real_escape_string()` is probably unnecessary but I always feel more secure when I use it.